# IAP or Payment Gateway?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm building an advertising platform for iOS and Android. This works quite similar to any other advertising platform where the advertisers can run ad campaigns until a credit limit they set. A user will be able to set custom credit limits. IAPs are fixed.

After a successful campaign, how should I charge the user? I was thinking to use PayPal gateway but seems like Google Play and App Store does not allow non-physical purchases inside an app except IAPs. I'm a bit confused how to do this.

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any update ? What you have done for this ?

Comment: @KishanBharda The project died. But now I've seen apps like Tinder allowing people to purchase digital goods using their CC.

Comment: Are you know how they does this ? Have any apis or anything else ?